# Best ERC-721 wallet for polygon chain technophobes

Tags: nft, erc-721, polygon

As the title suggests, I'm looking for advice in helping non-technical people install an app on both android, iOS that is super simple to use and that will then allow me to send them ERC-721 NFTs. They generally don't need to do anything with them after this point (i.e. send to others etc). Literally, just be able to view and show them. I've looked at alpha wallet (which is open source), but that might be overkill and then require a level of support and maintenance I can't devote to it.

Ideally, the NFTs would have their attributes and traits visible (although not 100% essential), also the metadata (all stored in IPFS) would easily be refreshable (I'm having issues with trust wallet not refreshing data and giving null images), and for the user to be able to on-board fairly easily without the mandatory storing of the recovery phrase until later.

The NFTs I am creating are of very little to zero monetary value.

Comment: [Argent](https://www.argent.xyz/) has quite good UX.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, Coinbase wallet or Rainbow wallet seems fit for your needs.

Both available on iOS and Android. Users will just need to install the app.

You don't need any permission to send NFTs to user wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't actually find one that wasn't chock full of subtle ads regarding buying crypto so I made my own web app in the end. It auto-generates a key-pair and saves the pub key to the web client. As stated, there's no value in the NFTs and so the web service can act as custodian up to the point the client wishes to take possession for realsies.